# Installing BF3 From Disc

Tags: battlefield-3

I am re-installing BF3 Premium on my machine and I purchased a physical copy of the game. When I stick the disc into my computer to install, Origin seems to be downloading the game instead of reading off my disc. Is there some setting I need to modify?

Comment: Have you tried installing it from disc while your computer is disconnected from the internet?

Comment: BTW. full BF3 Premium is 20GB, DVD is either 4.7GB (single layer) or at most 8.5GB (double layer). So you won't be able to install whole thing from DVD anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be the issue with the first BF3 release, so it might be same problem. Back then the solution was:

> - Delete the web download in Origin
> - Exit Origin
> - Restart installation from the disc and Origin found the disc and downloaded data from it rather than the net. Much faster!
>     [*(source)*](http://www.abc.net.au/technology/articles/2011/10/28/3350832.htm)

But keep in mind, that you won't be able to install whole thing from the disc. Full size of BF3 Premium (ie. base game + 5 DLCs) is 20GB. DVD's maximum size is 8.5GB (double layered). Also, depending on your DVD drive and your Internet connection, the speed improvement might not be that big. For example 8x DVD read speed is equal to 88Mbps, and that's purely theoretical maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different reasons, that this affects you.

Most known issues;

- You've bought a physical copy, but the key is a digital copy key. (Which means you got a key, that activates a download through Origin.
- Origin wants you to download. You might be able to disconnect from the internet and install from the disc.

I do recommend downloading it from Origin though.
Why?
Because there is bigger chances for mistakes in downloads from disc. You will also get latest patches and updates in the download. (Which you'll probably need to download anyway.)